# PHPunit - Testing class which uses class that has been tested in different test

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I can't find good information about this topic so I'm summoning this question. We're writing tests for our application. Now there are nested classes which use other classes and so on. Each class has its own test. E.g.:

```
// Some class
class SomeCalculator {
    public function add($a, $b): int {
        return $a + $b;
    }
}

// Its trivial test
class SomeCalculatorTest {
    public function testAdding() {
        $calc = new SomeCalculator();
        $this->assertEquals(2, $calc->add(1, 1));
    }
}
```

Now consider this:

```
// Some other class that uses SomeCalculator()
class SomePerson {
    protected $name;
    protected $age;

    public function __construct($name, $a, $b) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->age = (new SomeCalculator())->add($a, $b);
    }
    public function getName(): string {
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function getAge(): int {
        return $this->age;
    }
}

// Trivial test
class SomePersonTest {
    public function testCreating() {
        $person = new SomePerson('Horst', 1, 1);
        $this->assert('Horst', $person->getName());
        $this->assert(2, $person->getAge()); // should I remove this assert?
    }
}
```

Now the question is - while writing test for `SomePerson` should I assert also result of calculation of nested class `SomeCalculator`? Class `SomeCalculator` has its own tests so I am confident that it is OK.
I feel like we're duplicating `SomeCalculator`'s asserts in `SomeCalculatorTest` and in `SomePersonTest`.

Thanks.

Comment: No, you don't need to write tests twice for `SomeCalculator` class. Its tests should be written in its own separate test file.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But what if `SomePerson` has various conditions which could potentionally change behavior of `SomeCalculator`'s output? //cc @ArRakin

Comment: Mock other classes?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so main fault of this code is that it is hard to test. Assuming that `testCreating` is unit test it shouldn't have to check behavior of other components different than service under test. So let's take a look on example, and refactor it to be easier for testing:

```
        $this->age = (new SomeCalculator())->add($a, $b);
```

Main problem with example is above. Because of using new created object in constructor both classed are extremely coupled. To resolve that we should use **dependency inversion**, also we should separate class that only responsibility is to contain data (DTO?), from it creation by using for example **factory pattern**. In this case refactored example should look like this:

```
class SomePerson {
    protected $name;
    protected $age;

    public function __construct(string $name, int $age) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->age = $age;
    }
    public function getName(): string {
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function getAge(): int {
        return $this->age;
    }
}

class PersonFactory {

    private SomeCalculator $calculator;

    public function __construct(SomeCalculator $calculator) {
        $this->calculator = $calculator;
    }

    public function create($name, $a, $b): SomePerson 
    {
        return new SomePerson($name, $this->calculator->add($a, $b));
    }
}
```

And then test for it could look like this:

```
class PersonFactoryTest extends TestCase {

    public function testCreate(): string 
    {
        $a = 1;
        $b = 1;
        $age = 2;
        $name = 'Horst'
        $calculator = $this->createMock(SomeCalculator::class);
        $calculator->method('calculate')->with($a, $b)->willReturn($age);
        $factory = new PersonFactory($calculator);

        $person = $factory->create($name, $a, $b);

        $this->assertEqual($name, $person->getName());
        $this->assertEqual($age, $person->getAge());
    }
}
```

Using **mock** here is important, because from `PersonFactory` point of view behavior of calculator doesn't matter, so test should in this case test can only check if proper parameters are provided to add methody and if it result is used to creating new objects. Checking if calculator is adding correctly should be done in another tests.

Edit:

Because of mock it would be also be valid test (mocked values doesn't matter as long as they are mocked, but it would make it harder to understand for others programmers):

```
public function testCreate(): string 
{
    $a = 50;
    $b = -50;
    $age = 999;
    $name = 'Horst'
    $calculator = $this->createMock(SomeCalculator::class);
    $calculator->method('calculate')->with($a, $b)->willReturn($age);
    $factory = new PersonFactory($calculator);

    $person = $factory->create($name, $a, $b);

    $this->assertEqual($name, $person->getName());
    $this->assertEqual($age, $person->getAge());
}
```

Comment: Thans @Enzovera, I know about Factory pattern and we're using it. But even in your `PersonFactoryTest` you're using `$age = 2;` so you are actively testing result of `SomeCalculator`. So in this case if I'd change the logic inside `SomeCalculator` it will result in two failing tests (`PersonFactoryTest` and `SomeCalculatorTest`). What I asked was whether _I should test the result of `SomeCalculator` only in `SomeCalculatorTest` or in both `SomeCalculatorTest` AND in this case `PersonFactoryTest`_. :)

Comment: `$age = 2;` it is only example in this case easy to read and understand in human. If you mock it  you can change it in any way possible, and that will not make this test fails.